# How to output in buffer console output?

Tags: c++, console

How to output in buffer console output? For example I just need output of command "ipconfig -all", and want to store that information in some buffer?

Comment: Which os? What is buffer console output? What kind of buffer? etc

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033878/cross-platform-redirect-of-standard-input-and-output-of-spawned-process-in-native

Comment: Did you perhaps mean: "How to redirect the console output of another process to a buffer"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have an [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341)

What you really want to do is capture the output of another command. The whole "buffer" part is your first stab at an answer. It doesn't help you, and in fact it got you stuck thikning in the wrong direction.

badgerr offers some solutions, but the most common solution is `popen("ifconfig -a", "r")`. This doesn't return a buffer, it returns a `FILE*` that you can pass to `fread`. It's a POSIX function and available on Linux.

On Windows, you call `CreateProcess` and pass a `STARTUPINFO` structure containing `dwFlags=STARTF_USESTDHANDLES`, and `hStdOutput=ResultOfCreatePipe`.

Comment: thnx all for help, you give me exactly what I'm searching for :)

Answer (score 3):

You can write the output of a console application to a file (at least, in Windows), using the >  parameter.

For example, for your case you'd write ipconfig -all > C:\output.txt to write the information to output.txt.

Alternatively, if you're doing it in code, you could create a process that runs ipconfig, and read the standard output using Microsoft's convoluted methods http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499%28VS.85%29.aspx, or an application framework such as Qt, which simplifies process management http://qt.nokia.com/products/ - see QProcess: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.3/qprocess.html#readAllStandardOutput

Comment: It would be nice, if when someone downvotes, they leave a comment saying why. I'm here to learn as well.

Comment: Anonymous downvotes are one of my main dislikes about Stack Overflow.  I think this info is relevant and accurate so +1