# fgetc doesn't return to process

Tags: c++, windows, prettier

I'm trying to do something like `echo {a:1} | prettier --stdin-filepath index.js` and return the value returned in stdout.
But I also want to make this program platform independant.

Referencing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033878/cross-platform-redirect-of-standard-input-and-output-of-spawned-process-in-nativ) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output), I managed to write code like this:

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

HANDLE hChildStd_IN_Rd = NULL;
HANDLE hChildStd_IN_Wr = NULL;
HANDLE hChildStd_OUT_Rd = NULL;
HANDLE hChildStd_OUT_Wr = NULL;

int main() {
  const char source_code[] = "{a:1}";

  FILE *fd_OUT = nullptr, *fd_IN = nullptr;
#ifdef _WIN32
  try {
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr{};
    saAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

    if (!CreatePipe(&hChildStd_OUT_Rd, &hChildStd_OUT_Wr, &saAttr, 0))
      throw std::runtime_error("StdoutRd CreatePipe");
    if (!SetHandleInformation(hChildStd_OUT_Rd, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0))
      throw std::runtime_error("Stdout SetHandleInformation");
    if (!CreatePipe(&hChildStd_IN_Rd, &hChildStd_IN_Wr, &saAttr, 0))
      throw std::runtime_error("Stdin CreatePipe");
    if (!SetHandleInformation(hChildStd_IN_Wr, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0))
      throw std::runtime_error("Stdin SetHandleInformation");

    TCHAR szCmdline[] = TEXT(
        "C:\\Users\\yuto0214w\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\prettier.cmd "
        "--stdin-filepath index.js");

    PROCESS_INFORMATION piProcInfo;
    STARTUPINFO siStartInfo;
    ZeroMemory(&piProcInfo, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
    ZeroMemory(&siStartInfo, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));

    siStartInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    siStartInfo.hStdError = hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
    siStartInfo.hStdOutput = hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
    siStartInfo.hStdInput = hChildStd_IN_Rd;
    siStartInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

    if (!CreateProcess(NULL, szCmdline, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL,
                       &siStartInfo, &piProcInfo))
      throw std::runtime_error("CreateProcess");

    CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hThread);
    CloseHandle(hChildStd_OUT_Wr);
    CloseHandle(hChildStd_IN_Rd);

    fd_OUT = _fdopen(_open_osfhandle((intptr_t)hChildStd_OUT_Rd, _O_RDONLY), "r");
    fd_IN = _fdopen(_open_osfhandle((intptr_t)hChildStd_IN_Wr, _O_WRONLY), "w");
  } catch (std::exception& e) {
    std::cout << std::string("Encountered an error when running: ") + e.what()
              << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }
#else
  // pipe fork dup2 execlp fdopen
#endif
  fputs(source_code, fd_IN);

  std::string formatted_code;
  int c;
  while ((c = fgetc(fd_OUT)) != EOF) {
    formatted_code += c;
    std::cout << "ch: " << c << std::endl; // For testing
  }

  fclose(fd_OUT);
  fclose(fd_IN);

  std::cout << formatted_code << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

This will compile, but stops completely on `fgetc`. I mean stops completely by it doesn't show any `ch:`.

I built program using MSVC v143.

Thanks

Comment: You might find [boost.process](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/doc/html/process.html) easier than trying to write all this stuff yourself

Comment: You could use `popen`  (called `_popen` in Windows)

Comment: @AlanBirtles Yes, I think boost is great option here, though I would use it as last resort.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I need to redirect both stdin and stdout, so I can't.

Comment: Does this help: https://docs.octave.org/doxygen/6.1.0/d3/d09/octave-popen2_8c_source.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I wasn't closing `fd_IN` before reading `fd_OUT`.

This causes deadlock because prettier is awaiting input from program, and program is awaiting output from prettier.

To fix this,

```cpp
  fputs(source_code, fd_IN);
  fclose(fd_IN);

  std::string formatted_code;
  int c;
  while ((c = fgetc(fd_OUT)) != EOF) {
    formatted_code += c;
    std::cout << "ch: " << c << std::endl; // For testing
  }

  fclose(fd_OUT);
```